# PHP Array desaparece al invocar cierto valor de db

Tags: php, mysql, json, php7

tengo una base de datos la cual tiene nombres ids, y otros valores los cuales puedo generar con normalidad, sin embargo al generar los nombres el array desaparece y la página carga en blanco. Pienso que quizá deba extraer el dato de alguna otra manera y es por ello que vengo a pedir apoyo:

```
array_push($result,
array(
'car'=>$row[0],
'cod'=>$row[1],
'nom'=>$row[2], <---- si está en 2 la pagina sale en blanco-->
'Per01'=>$row[3],      asi que le cambio a 1 y me aparece todo el array 
'Per02'=>$row[4],      
'Per03'=>$row[5],
'Per04'=>$row[6],
'Prom'=>$row[7]
));
}
$json = json_encode(['result' => $result]);

echo $json;
```

¿Cuál sería la mejor manera de invocar ese dato?, ¿Será por que la tabla tiene muchos valores? ya que tiene nombres y apellidos

Comment: No se entiende lo que quieres decir con esto: *`sin embargo al generar los nombres el array desaparece`*  ¿? Si estás guardando los datos desde una consulta SQL, no sé si sabes que `mysqli` y PDO tienen formas muy simples de hacer lo que parece que intentas hacer a mano. Pon el contexto del código y podremos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: hago un select * a la base de datos con php y el resultado lo paso a json pero solo con la tabla "nombres" mi seleccion desaparece asi que no tengo manera de mostrar esos resultados

Comment: No logro entender qué es lo que quieres, por favor pulsa en [edit] y explica con más claridad la situación y si es posible pon el trozo de código completo. Creo que esto se puede lograr de una forma más sencilla.

Comment: ya lo arreglé de cierta manera, resulta que la seleccion se ponia en blanco ya que los nombres tenian caracteres que debia encodear a utf8

Comment: @G.Romero y por qué no has configurado la conexión con MySQL en utf-8 y así no necesitas hacer un `utf8_encode()`? ¿Usas mysqli o PDO/mysql?